# Wordpress Google Fonts Fallback

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, fallback

So i´m having trouble setting up a fallback font for my google webfonts.

For my menu i use Lobster, which looks like this:

```
.menu.main li {
font-family: 'Lobster Two',  cursive;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 13pt;
float: left;
padding: 6px 25px 0px 25px;
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
}
```

On many mobile devices lobster will not load for some reason, so i want the menu to be helvetica. i tried this:

```
font-family: 'Lobster Two', Helvetica,  cursive;
font-family: 'Lobster Two', "Helvetica, cursive;
font-family: 'Lobster Two', 'Helvetica', cursive;
```

None of these works. The Menu now just shows up in Helvetica. Where is the fault i did?

That´s how i got the fonts to wordpress:

```
 function load_fonts() {
        wp_register_style('googleFonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two|Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'googleFonts');
    }

add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_fonts');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
```

This might be a good fallback stack (remove the neue if you don't like it..)

The problem is that **"Since WordPress 3.3 wp_print_styles should not be used to enqueue styles or scripts"**.

So you need to use **wp_enqueue_scripts**, in fact if you check the output code you can see that lobster is not loaded.

Comment: thats the link: http://latin-festival.viv-werbeagentur.de/?page_id=104

my css looks like this now: font-family: "Lobster Two", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 

which does not work again cause it now shows me the helvetica as standard font in my menu, but i only want it to use helvetica if lobster does not work